# How to wait for axWebBrowser to finish loading?

Tags: c#, webforms, axwebbrowser

I am using `axWebBrowser` to do some web automation.
When the system triggers the `NewWindow2` event, it is unable to keep track of an HTML element in the new window. After debugging, I noticed that the `axWebBrowser1.ReadyState` is equal to `ReadyState_Complete` although the new window hasn't finished loading.

```
private void axWebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEvent e) {            
    if (axWebBrowser1.ReadyState == SHDocVw.tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE) {
        // some code...
    }
}
```

How can I wait for the new window to finish loading so I can detect the HTML element in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can handle the `ProgressChanged` event:

```
private void webBrowser_ProgressChanged(object sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs e)  
{  
  siteLoading.Value = (int)e.CurrentProgress;
  if (e.CurrentProgress >= e.MaximumProgress)
  {
    // Loaded.
  }
}
```

Take a look the the following questions:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=526871
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/8785ddcc-6f48-410b-8cd4-122b3f2b0e34

Comment: thanks for your fast reply kamyar.  The code that you provide is not working because i'm using axWebBrowser (Com component)...

Comment: @Den: It seems like handling DocumentComplete event id the standard way. look at: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_22598363.html and http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=557963 and http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Misc/Q_21043365.html

Comment: Google the address, navigate to the bottom of the page, you'll see the result.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=gsihc&xhr=t&q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.experts-exchange.com%2FProgramming%2FLanguages%2F.NET%2FVisual_Basic.NET%2FQ_22598363.html&cp=91&pf=p&sclient=psy&site=&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_22598363.html&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=23daeab4d2e2d925 can you view now?

Comment: Hmm. strange. Have you scrolled to the very bottom? it shows you the subscription message, but you can see the result at the end.

Comment: What i saw after i have scrolled to the very bottom is the message left by VBRocks and Kanus. VBRocks's answer is not working for me. It is only working for WebBrowser but not AxWebBrowser. I'm facing the problem of axWebBrowser1.ReadyState is equal to ReadyState_Complete although the AxWebbrowser hasn't load finish. Therefore,i'm looking for other solution. Kamyar,do you have any idea?